# C++: get time zone deviation

Tags: c++, time, timezone

So I want to creata a time stamp (as a string) with the format `HH:MM:SS` in C++. I use `std::chrono` to get a unix time stamp and then calculate the hours, minutes and seconds.

```cpp
// Get unix time stamp in seconds.
const auto unix_time_stamp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
long long seconds_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(unix_time_stamp.time_since_epoch()).count();

// Calculate current time (hours, minutes, seconds).
uint8_t hours = (seconds_since_epoch % 86400) / 3600;
uint8_t minutes = (seconds_since_epoch % 3600) / 60;
uint8_t seconds = (seconds_since_epoch % 60);

// Create strings for hours, minutes, seconds.
std::string hours_string = std::to_string(hours);
std::string minutes_string = std::to_string(minutes);
std::string seconds_string = std::to_string(seconds);

// Check if the number is only one digit. If it is, add a 0 in the beginning (5:3:9 --> 05:03:09).
if(hours_string.size() == 1)
{
  hours_string = "0" + hours_string;
}
if(minutes_string.size() == 1)
{
  minutes_string = "0" + minutes_string;
}
if(seconds_string.size() == 1)
{
  seconds_string = "0" + seconds_string;
}

// Append to a final string.
std::string time_stamp = hours_string + ":" + minutes_string + ":" + seconds_string;
```

This is all working fine and great but there is one big problem: time zones.
With this way, I'm only calculating the time stamp for GMT. Is there any easy, fast and, most importantly, **portable** way to get the "offset" in seconds or minutes or hours for your system's time zone? By "portable" I mean platform-independent.

*Please note: I know you can do all of this more easily with `std::strftime` and so on, but I really want to implement this by myself.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some implementations of `std::tm` will contain a member that has the local offset as a member.  ...  But it isn't portable.

One trick is to take your `seconds_since_epoch`, and either assign it to a `std::time_t`, or just make its type `std::time_t` in the first place instead of `long long`.

... Oh, wait that isn't quite portable.  Some platforms still use a 32 bit `time_t`.  But assuming a 64 bit `time_t` ...

Then use `localtime` to get a `std::tm`:

```
std::tm tm = *localtime(&seconds_since_epoch);
```

This isn't officially portable because `system_clock` and `time_t` aren't guaranteed to have the same epoch.  But in practice they do.

Now take the `{year, month, day, hour, minute, second}` fields out of the `tm` and compute a "local epoch".  The hard part of this computation is converting the `{year, month, day}` part into a count of days.  You can use `days_from_civil` from [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil) to do that computation efficiently.  Be sure to take the weird offsets into account for `tm_year` and `tm_mon` when doing this.

After you get this then subtract `seconds_since_epoch` from it:

```
 auto offset = local_epoch - seconds_since_epoch;
```

This is your signed UTC offset in seconds.  Positive is east of the prime meridian.

---

In C++20 this simplifies down to:

```
auto offset = std::chrono::current_zone()->get_info(system_clock::now()).offset;
```

and `offset` will have type `std::chrono::seconds`.

You can get a [free, open-source preview of this here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  It does require some [installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

Comment: Howard - just want to drop a note to say that I continue to be impressed with your efforts both in helping the community and in bringing date/time/timezone improvements to C++20.  THANK YOU.